# Getting null for embedded components on DXA 1.5

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.5, embedded-items

We are migrating from DXA 1.2 to DXA 1.5.
As part of that we had set up personalized modules and initializing the modules accordingly using `ModuleInitializer` with that specific area name.

For some reasons, we are not getting the embedded Components like images on `Footer` Schema.

In `moduleinitializer`, we had registered the `Footer` View as well as `Image` model separately.

## Can someone please help us.

Below is the code of ModuleInitializer

```
//Page Model
@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "PlainCodeTextPV", modelClass = PageModelImpl.class),
//@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "CDAResponsivePV", modelClass = PageModelImpl.class),
//@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "CDARobotPV", modelClass = PageModelImpl.class),
@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "ResponsivePV", modelClass = PageModelImpl.class),
@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "GeneralPage", modelClass = PageModelImpl.class),
@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "IncludePage", modelClass = PageModelImpl.class),
@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "RedirectPage", modelClass = PageModelImpl.class),

@RegisteredViewModel(modelClass = Image.class),

@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "Footer", modelClass = RegionModelImpl.class),    

@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "FooterCV", modelClass = Footer.class),
})


public class CoreModuleInitializer extends AbstractInitializer {
@Override
protected String getAreaName() {
    System.out.println("Inside Area Name:: Core" );
    return "Test";
    }
}
```

========
Model Java

@SemanticEntity(entityName = "Footer", vocabulary = SDL_CORE, prefix = "tri", public_ = true)
public class Footer extends AbstractEntityModel {

```
@JsonProperty("Heading")
@SemanticProperty("tri:heading")
private String heading;

@JsonProperty("ContactUsLink")
@SemanticProperty("tri:contactUsLink")
private Link contactUsLink;

@JsonProperty("AdditionText")
@SemanticProperty("tri:additionText")
private RichText additionText;

@SemanticProperty("tri:socialMediaIcons")
@JsonProperty("SocialMediaIcons")
private List<SocialMediaSharing> socialMediaIcons;

@SemanticProperty("tri:footerLinks")
@JsonProperty("FooterLinks")
private List<Link> footerLinks;

@JsonProperty("ChairImage")
@SemanticProperty("tri:chairImage")
private Image chairImage;

@JsonProperty("SiteMap")
@SemanticProperty("tri:siteMap")
private SiteIndexContent siteMap;

public SiteIndexContent getSiteMap() {
    return siteMap;
}

public void setSiteMap(SiteIndexContent siteMap) {
    this.siteMap = siteMap;
}

public Image getChairImage() {
    return chairImage;
}

public Link getContactUsLink() {
    return contactUsLink;
}

public List<Link> getFooterLinks() {
    return footerLinks;
}

public String getHeading() {
    return heading;
}

public List<SocialMediaSharing> getSocialMediaIcons() {
    return socialMediaIcons;
}

public void setChairImage(Image chairImage) {
    this.chairImage = chairImage;
}

public void setContactUsLink(Link contactUsLink) {
    this.contactUsLink = contactUsLink;
}

public void setFooterLinks(List<Link> footerLinks) {
    this.footerLinks = footerLinks;
}

public void setHeading(String heading) {
    this.heading = heading;
}


public RichText getAdditionText() {
    return additionText;
}

public void setAdditionText(RichText additionText) {
    this.additionText = additionText;
}
```

## }

@SemanticEntity(entityName = "ImageObject", vocabulary = SDL_CORE, prefix = "tri", public_ = true)
//@ToString
@Slf4j
public class Image extends MediaItem {

```
@SemanticProperty("tri:name")
@JsonProperty("AlternateText")
@Getter
@Setter
private String alternateText;

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
@JsonIgnore
public boolean isImage() {
    return true;
}
```

.....
   ....
}

Comment: Did you know the latest release of DXA is 1.6, if you are currently busy migrating, you might as well make sure you are migrating to the latest? The changes between 1.2 and 1.6 on the `ModuleInitializer` all come down to the changes in the `AbstractInitializer`, maybe it is useful if you edit your question and add the code of your 1.2 `ModuleInitializer` and the current one so it is clear what changes you have made?

Comment: Thanks Bart for the response. i had corrected my question by adding the code.

Comment: Also we had spent a lot of time in bringing DXA 1.5 sample code up. Not sure if we can make the changes now. So would like to stick with DXA 1.5 for now.

Comment: Can you describe the problem more specifically? How does the problematic View Model look?

Comment: Added the models in the question

Comment: What is the Title of the MM Schema you use for your Images?  The `@SemanticEntity` annotation on your `Image` class looks suspicious; it seems to be a mix of a schema.org mapping (`entityName = "ImageObject", public_ = true`) and an explicit, internal mapping (`vocabulary = SDL_CORE`).

Answer (score 1):

We found the root cause for the issue.

The problem was in the way the our custom module was initialized. Namely, the SemanticMapper was not called on the model inside Emerald module. We added the necessary code to registerEntitites() in the EmeraldInitializer class.

@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@ModuleInfo(name = "Emerald module", areaName = "Emerald", description = "Emerald DXA module which contains basic views")
public class EmeraldCoreModuleInitializer extends AbstractInitializer {
    @Override
    protected String getAreaName() {
        return "Emerald";
        }

```
@Autowired
private SemanticMappingRegistry semanticMappingRegistry;
@PostConstruct
private void registerModels() {
    semanticMappingRegistry.registerEntities(getClass().getPackage().getName());
}
```

}

Great thanks to @'Mihai Cădariu'  for helping in resolving this issue.